# Solving a delayed differential equation in Matlab to reproduce a published figure

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a delayed differential equation in Matlab:

```
mRNA' = k0 + k*Activator(t-delta_t) - gamma*mRNA(t)
```

In this equation

```
k0 is constant, representing basal transcription (production) of mRNA; 
k is another constant parameter representing the rate of Activator stimulated mRNA production that is dependent on the amount of Activator at time t-delta_t;
gamma is another constant representing the rate of degradation of mRNA 
mRNA at time t is the amount of mRNA at time t.
```

I'm trying to simulate this equation so that I can mess around and see how it behaves with different parameters (i.e. different time delays, comparisons with ODE's etc.). I'm following the code example [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/dde-with-constant-delays.html) with limited success.

My code so far is:

```
function General_mRNA_DDE
  sol = dde23(@General_mRNA_DDE2,2,@input_function,[0,5])


  figure; 
  plot(sol.x,sol.y)


  function dydt =  General_mRNA_DDE2(t,y,z)
  k0=1;
  k=10;
  mRNA0=1; %initial concentration of mRNA
  gamma=0.1;
  z
  dydt= [k0 + k*z - gamma*y];
  end

  function hist = input_function(t)
      hist = 1;
  end


  end
```

But what I have essentially looks like a very steep exponential curve. Here is what I'm trying to reproduce:

[image]

From this paper doi: 10.15252/msb.20177554 (http://msb.embopress.org/content/msb/13/5/928.full.pdf)

Does anybody have any advice for me to accurately reproduce the figure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a time-delayed differential equation, as the derivative and value of the unknown mRNA are taken from the same time. That the value of the control function is from a delayed time is not important if the Activator value does not depend on the mRNA value at that previous time.

You can apply an integrating factor `exp(gamma*t)` so that the new differential equation

```
 ( exp(gamma*t) * mRNA(t) )' = exp(gamma*t) * ( k0 + k*Activator(t-delta_t) )
```

can be solved by simple integrations, esp. if the Activator function is piecewise constant.